# Why do female humans invest more in parental care than male humans, from an evolutionary standpoint?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, evolution, human-genetics, human-evolution

As the question title suggests, why do female humans invest more in parental care than male humans, from an evolutionary standpoint?

My guess is that the crux of this that males and females have different reproductive biology, but this by itself would not a very satisfying answer, due it not being very comprehensive.

Comment: Have you investigated closely related species? Do you know [Bateman's principle](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39955/why-are-female-not-competitive-for-reproduction-like-males/39964#39964) and the [theory of parental investment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parental_investment)?

Comment: Do you have a source that they do invest more? I have not seen research showing an non-cultural variation.

Comment: I am voting to close as unclear until the OP adresses the questions in comments.

Comment: "too broad"??? That's a GREAT QUESTION!! How can you erase it? Leave those inexpensive few kB for us to use our brains!

Comment: That's a BIOLOGY site. Most evolutionary questions are broad. How can we think biology, how can we think evolution, if "broad thinking" is not allowed? Biology is so close to philosophy, yet you keep pulling them apart!

Comment: @BiologyStudent: in Mammals, in general, the long pregnant state, plus the breastfeed, etc causes females usually displaying much more parental care than the males, because they already invested so much. In other animals, like some fish and birds, where the males build and ornament the nest, the reverse is expected.

Comment: @anongoodnurse was that too broad for you?

Comment: @AliceD was that too broad for you?

Comment: @Remi.b was that too broad for you?

Comment: @kmm was that too broad for you?

Comment: @David was that too broad for you?

Comment: And really? All this should need not even 1kB!